# Django管理サイトで外部キーで紐づいている別テーブルの情報を紐づけたい。

Tags: python, django

Django管理サイトで外部キーで紐づいている別テーブルの情報を紐づけたいのですが可能でしょうか？

例として下記のような３つのテーブルを考えました。
model.py

```
from django.db import models
class ShopUserRelation(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.ForeignKey('Shop', db_column = 'shop_id')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('User', db_column = 'user_id')

class Shop(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length = 128)

class User(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
```

Django管理サイトでShopUserRelationのレコードの一覧画面で
id, shop.name, user.name を一覧として出力したいのですが、可能でしょうか。
下記のような並び順で出力されることが理想です。
よろしくお願いします。

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

class ShopUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'shop_name', 'user_name')

admin.site.register(ShopUser, ShopUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Shop, ShopAdmin)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Djangoのドキュメントに書き方が載っていました。
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

以下のように書けば良さそうです.

admin.py::

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

class ShopUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'shop_name', 'user_name')
    def shop_name(self, obj):
        return obj.shop_id.name
    shop_name.short_description = 'Shop Name'

    def user_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user_id.name
    shop_name.short_description = 'User Name'

admin.site.register(ShopUser, ShopUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Shop, ShopAdmin)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```