# Django管理サイトで別テーブルの情報にフィルタをかけたい。

Tags: python, django

[Django管理サイトで外部キーで紐づいている別テーブルの情報を紐づけたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/35148/)

先ほど、上記の質問で外部キーに設定している
↓のテーブルがあるときに
別テーブルの情報を引っ張ってくる方法を教えてもらいました。

model.py

```
from django.db import models
class ShopUserRelation(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.ForeignKey('Shop', db_column = 'shop_id')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('User', db_column = 'user_id')

class Shop(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length = 128)

class User(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
```

admin.py

```
class ShopUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'shop_name', 'user_name')
    def shop_name(self, obj):
        return obj.shop_id.name
    shop_name.short_description = 'Shop Name'

    def user_name(self, obj):
        return obj.user_id.name
    shop_name.short_description = 'User Name'
```

この追加したshop_nameとuser_nameをフィルタしたいのですが、可能でしょうか。
下記のようなコードをadmin.pyに追記すると、
idではフィルタをかけることが可能ですが、shop_nameとuser_nameではフィルタすることはできませんでした。

```
list_filter  = ['id', 'shop_name', 'user_name']
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django の list_filter(及びORM)ではForeignKeyのフィールドにアクセスしたい場合は 「model__field」 とアンダースコアを二つ続けて書くことでアクセスできます。したがって下記のように `shop__name` としてみてください。

```
list_filter  = ['id', 'shop__name', 'user___name']
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships